# REGEX Force Uppercase Syntax

Tags: regex, forms, passwords

I'm using jquery's validator plugin to validate my registration form. I made a custom rule for password validation. I make it so that it has to follow the following rules:
1) Must be a minimum of 8 characters
2) Must contain at least 1 number 
3) Must contain at least 1 symbol 
4) Must contain at least 1 upper-case letter

Here's my code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UcKW8/4/)

Including this expression:

```
/^(?=.*[\W])(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/i
```

This enforced almost all the above 4 policies except for the last one, it doesn't enforce that there must be at least 1 uppercase. I have no idea why, I've search all the regex documentations to make sure I got the syntax correct. And even this only tool tells me i'm right: [ruby](http://rubular.com/r/ps9kwazOKa)

Any ideas why it's not working properly? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `i` at the end of your regex makes it case insensitive. So every uppercase letter you specified will also match the corresponding lowercase letter. Remove that `i` and it should work.

Comment: @Richard wait you're not even the OP ^^ ... then I haven't said anything